# TCPDF: How to store a pdf page separately?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

My php script generates a multiple page document with TCPDF like that:

```
foreach($data as $dataRow) {
   // ....
   $this->WriteHTMLCell(...);
   $this->AddPage();
}

$this->Output(...);
```

This works perfectly. But now i have to store each single page separately. In other words: Every foreach-iteration must store the current page as a single pdf file. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you wanting to access the pdfs that are created? Could you move the new pdf and output statement into your foreach loop, saving the output to your file system?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `$this->Output(...);` function inside to the foreach function.

```
foreach($data as $dataRow) 
{
    // ....
    $this->WriteHTMLCell(...);
    $this->AddPage();

    $this->Output(...);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not help. If i output/persist the pdf contents to a file, the file from the second iteration contains the first, the third iteration contains the first and the second and so on. I just want to store each page separately AND the multi-paged file.

Answer (score 0):

Document output method for each interation:

```
$page=1;
foreach($data as $dataRow) {
   // ....
   $this->WriteHTMLCell(...);
   $this->Output("document-page-".$page,"I");
   $page++;
}
```